# How can I import a node js project to another node js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use `/folder1/folder2/a.js` in  `/folder3/folder4/b.js`.

In `b.js`, i tried

```
var a = require('../folder1/folder2/a.js');
```

but this is not working. Please suggest me the correct way to do this.

```
error:module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^
```

> > Error: Cannot find module '../folder1/folder2/a.js'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\502660706\workspace\folder3\folder4\b.js:1:85)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)

Comment: Are you going up enough paths? Might need to do `../../folder1/folder2/a.js`

Comment: Could you please include the output of the following commands (to make sure this is not a pathing issue):

`ls ../`

`ls ../folder1`

`ls ../folder1/folder2`

Comment: You just got the path wrong.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This worked. I tried
var tjConnectorNode = require('../../../workspace/folder1/folder2/a.js');
i dont know how it is considering the path. I just tried and its working.
Can anyone explain me how this works

Comment: Just read up on relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

according to the output message you're giving a wrong path of the file.

> Error: Cannot find module '